# Using For Loop to Add Numbers to a Vector

Tags: c++

I want to add numbers 1 through 10 to an empty vector using a for loop. So I know that it should look like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++){

//some code that adds 1 - 10 to a vector

}
```

After the code has ran, I should get a vector that looks like this: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: @bolov: You can't do that to an empty vector.

Comment: enjoy this. It is not often you get excellent answers to not so good question.

Answer (score 3):

```
const int N = 10;

std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve( N );

for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) v.push_back( i );
```

Or

```
const int N = 10;

std::vector<int> v( N );

int i = 1;
for ( int &x : v ) x = i++;
```

Or

```
#include <numeric>

//...

const int N = 10;

std::vector<int> v( N );

std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 1 );
```

Or

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

const int N = 10;

std::vector<int> v( N );

int i = 1;
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&i]( int &x ) { x = i++; } );
```

Or

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

const int N = 10;

std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve( N );

int i = 1;
std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), N, [&i] { return i++; } );
```

All these methods use for loop

Comment: Vlad! Who else to expect to answer on these kind of _semi VLQ_ question (don't have more words for it, as what's already has been said in the past).

Comment: in the first example it should be `v.push_back( i + 1 )`

Comment: @Slava Thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  You wanted to say who else will help except Vlad?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow actually it should be `int i = 1`, did not pay attention to `i <= N`, nevermind you fixed it properly

Comment: @bolov Do you mean algorithm std::iota?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow _"... who else will help except Vlad?"_ No. I wanted to express that acting like this, isn't _helping_ at all, for the long term view of the SO site, and it has been stated many times before. You exactly know what I mean, and will flag this comment as _unconstructive_ again (or downvote some of my questions).

Comment: @bolov See my proposal. http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-20-00000046-000-0-0-1352203696 Though it is written in Russian but you can translate it in English using for example bing.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply pushing value in the vector.. as the vector has a property of push_back to add value in it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  for(int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
     myvector.push_back(i);

  return 0;
}
```

the vector will then contain : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

For more You can read this references: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/