# How to use a for loop to add elements to a vec or a rowvec?

Tags: c++, armadillo

Trying to use a for loop to add elements in a vec or a rowvec, but each time the loop adds an element, the matrix resets each time?

Noob in Armadillo, I've looked at the documentation but I can't even find a single sample example where they use for loops. Thanks for any help.

```
arma::vec A;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    A << i;
}
cout << A;
```

Expected output : 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0

Actual output : 9.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using For Loop to Add Numbers to a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847128/using-for-loop-to-add-numbers-to-a-vector)

Comment: @scohe001 That duplicate does not quite apply since OP is working with `arma::vec`s instead of `std::vector`s.

Comment: You should be able to use regular [`element access`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) to initialize your values, though it probably isn't optimal in terms of performance.

Comment: @0x5453 ahh I didn't even realize the tag, I thought it was just poorly written C++. In that case, this may be a better dupe: [push_back/append or appending a vector with a loop in C++ Armadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28247490/2602718)

Comment: why the downvote, this is a great question. The answer is not obvious. THe docs do not say how to push a new element into a vec

Comment: I suggest you explicitly specify the namespace in your question's code (e.g., `arma::vec A;` instead of `vec A;`) to avoid confusion with other libraries such as the STL. It might reduce errors by viewers.

Comment: What happens if you use the insertion operator on `A` again? Like this: `cout << A << " " << A;`.

Comment: BTW, in embedded systems, you want to stay away from dynamic memory allocation.  Search the internet for "c++ dynamic memory fragmentation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to accomplish this. The first approach is to simply declare the size of the vector beforehand and [set](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) the individual elements:

```
arma::vec A(10);
for (arma::uword i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    A(i) = i;
}
```

If you don't know how many elements you need beforehand, follow the other approaches detailed in the answers to: [push_back/append or appending a vector with a loop in C++ Armadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247490/push-back-append-or-appending-a-vector-with-a-loop-in-c-armadillo)